# Excel scatterplot chart from List(Of Decimal) values - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts, series

Is it possible to create a plot from `List(Of Decimal)` values in Excel with VB?  I would like to avoid dumping data directly into a table, then creating the chart from that.  Here is what I have so far, but I am getting a data type mismatch when I try to assign `.XValues` and `.Values` to the list.  Is there some sort of conversion that needs to happen to turn a list into a series?

```
    Dim Series As Excel.Series
    Dim xVals As New List(Of Decimal)(New Decimal() {1, 3, 4, 5})
    Dim yVals As New List(Of Decimal)(New Decimal() {2, 2, 2, 2})
    xlWorkSheet = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

    xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    xlWorkSheet.Name = "My Sheet"
    xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
    xlChartObj = xlCharts.Add(150, 30, 400, 250)
    xlChart = xlChartObj.Chart

    With xlChart
        .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionRight
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Test Chart"
        For i = 0 To channels.Count - 1
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            Series = .SeriesCollection(i + 1)
            Series.XValues = xVals
            Series.Values = yvals
        Next
        .Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet)
    End With
```

UPDATE:

I seems like the following code will work, but it is not very ideal.  Is there a better way to do this other than converting the array to a string representation of the array like I did?

```
    Dim Series As Excel.Series
    Dim xVals As New List(Of Decimal)(New Decimal() {1, 3, 4, 5})
    Dim yVals As New List(Of Decimal)(New Decimal() {2, 2, 2, 2})
    Dim xString As String
    Dim yString As String
    xlWorkSheet = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)

    xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    xlWorkSheet.Name = "My Sheet"
    xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
    xlChartObj = xlCharts.Add(150, 30, 400, 250)
    xlChart = xlChartObj.Chart

    With xlChart
        .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionRight
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Test Chart"
        For i = 0 To channels.Count - 1
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            Series = .SeriesCollection(i + 1)

            xString = "={"
            xString += xVals(0).ToString
            For k = 1 To xVals.Count - 1
                xString += ","
                xString += xVals(k).ToString
            Next
            xString = "}"

            yString = "={"
            yString += yVals(0).ToString
            For k = 1 To yVals.Count - 1
                yString += ","
                yString += yVals(k).ToString
            Next
            yString = "}"

            Series.XValues = xString
            Series.Values = yString
        Next
        .Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet)
    End With
```

Comment: Have you tried using arrays in place of Lists?

Comment: I tried changing the `Series.XValues = xVals` to `Series.XValues = xVals.ToArray`,  but I am now getting the errors `Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` and `Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))`

Comment: @Tim I also tried `Series.XValues = Array(1,3,4,5)` but for some reason it doesn't like my using Array() like that and gives me `'Array' is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: I think you'd use `Series.XValues = New Decimal() {1,3,4,5}`

Comment: @TimWilliams I get a `Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))` for that

Comment: I see you came up with a solution which works. You might find using (eg) `Series.XValues = "={" + String.Join(",", xVals) + "}"` is simpler than looping through your arrays to build the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted with the following code using Ranges stored as objects.  The string method I mentioned in my second block of code had a limit of 8000+ characters (not sure of actual number, 8192?).

```
Dim Series As Excel.Series
Dim xVals As New List(Of Decimal)(New Decimal() {1, 3, 4, 5})
Dim yVals As New List(Of Decimal)(New Decimal() {2, 2, 2, 2})
Dim xRange As Object
Dim yRange As Object
Dim tempSheet as Excel.Worksheet

xlWorkSheet = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
xlWorkSheet.Activate()
xlWorkSheet.Name = "My Sheet"
xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
xlChartObj = xlCharts.Add(150, 30, 400, 250)
xlChart = xlChartObj.Chart

With xlChart
    .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines
    .HasLegend = True
    .Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionRight
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Test Chart"
    For i = 0 To channels.Count - 1
        tempSheet = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
        tempSheet.Activate()
        With tempSheet
            .Visible = False
            For k = 0 To xVals.Count - 1
                tempSheet.Cells(k + 1, 1).Value = xVals(k)
                tempSheet.Cells(k + 1, 2).Value = yVals(k) 'Assumes yVals.Count = xVals.Count
            Next
            xRange = tempSheet.Range("A1:A" + xVals.Count.ToString).Value
            yRange = tempSheet.Range("B1:B" + xVals.Count.ToString).Value
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Delete()
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With

        Series = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
        With Series
            .XValues = xRange
            .Values = yRange
        End With            
    Next
    .Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Excel does best when it is plotting data from a worksheet. Is there any reason not to dump your Lists (or arrays) into the worksheet, and use these ranges as the chart series source data?

Comment: I am plotting multiple different data sets with different time scales and time duration's and putting them on the same plot.  I am storing hundreds of arrays of these data sets in VB and would rather not clutter an excel file with a new tab for each data set.  I also don't want the user to be able to modify any of the data.  It just made the most sense to me to do it this way.

Comment: You could hide the sheets, using the xlVeryHidden value for Sheet.Visible, and the user interface won't even show it.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't consider it cluttering a sheet if you're putting data on it for plotting in a chart. Especially since that is how charts work most reliably.